# Issue in writing image to xlsx file using XlsxReaderWriter

Tags: ios, xcode, image, xlsx

I am trying to write image in xlsx file using [this](https://github.com/charlymr/XlsxReaderWriter) library, as per the document suggests method to write image in xlsx file i followed the same but was unable to succeed.

Below are the code snippet that i used to write images

First method

```
Worksheet.add(image, inCellReferenced: "A2", withOffset: CGPoint(x:15, y:10), size: (image?.size)! , preserveTransparency: true)
```

Second method

```
let drawing: BRAWorksheetDrawing = Worksheet.add(image, betweenCellsReferenced: "C2", and: "D2", with: UIEdgeInsets.zero, preserveTransparency: false)
drawing.insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Using this both methods i was unable to write the images to xlsx file, any help will be great.!

Comment: Any solution u found

Comment: @AsmaGodil Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this helped me

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage, 0.5)
          let image = UIImage(data: data!)

          let drawing: BRAWorksheetDrawing = firstWorksheet.add(image, betweenCellsReferenced: startCell, and: endCell, with: UIEdgeInsets.zero, preserveTransparency: true)

          drawing.shouldKeepAspectRatio = false
```